# Selecting a running android application from Status bar

Tags: android

My application is running and my icon is showing while the app is running.  When I go to select the application from the drop down nothing happens.

I have to go and click the icon of the program again to get it to launch. I'm sure I am missing some easy code somewhere. I'm no expert so any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about an entry you've created in the notification bar. When you create your notification, one of the parameters is a `PendingIntent`. This describes the `Intent` to invoke when the user selects your entry. Set that up to start your activity and it will happen.